# Missing lines in the Protovis Chart

Tags: javascript, protovis

I'm using the Parallel Coordinate Chart from the following link

http://mbostock.github.io/protovis/ex/cars-full.html

With identical cars-full.html, ex.css, cars.js and protovis-r3.2.js, the chart is displayed with missing lines. (see picture below)

[Local version of Parallel Coordinate Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZOT6.png)

Anybody has any idea on what could possibly go wrong here?

Comment: Can you show us your code ? Also what data you're using ? Also f12 will show you console // debugging in chrome.

Comment: The code is exact replicate of the code posted on the link. F12 does not show any error.

Comment: So do you have a copy of the `cars.js` file locally also which contains the data object ? IE : http://mbostock.github.io/protovis/ex/cars.js, the code is obviously not the exact same though..

Comment: Yes. cars.js is present. The code is available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i386hi8o3ic9yrl/parallel_chart.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved by rewriting it based on the code at github.com/mbostock/protovis/tree/master/examples/cars.